# Gitlab Wiki - How to import wiki when importing a repository

Tags: import, gitlab, wiki, gitlab-ce

I have a Gitlab CE 11.7 docker running on my server. When I import a project from gitlab.com, its wiki is missing. I use the built-in interface to import the projects:

`New Project > Import project [tab] > GitLab.com [button]`

then I choose the repository to import from a list of repositories connected to my account.

Is there a way to migrate the wiki of a repository from Gitlab.com to a GitLab CE instance?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Wikis are repos as well.  You can clone a project by doing:

```
git clone https://gitlab.com/{namespace}/{project}.wiki.git
```

If you click the "Git Access" link at the top in your wiki, you also get this URL.

Since it is a repo you can then push to the desired destination wiki.

Answer (score 7):

The valid answer is just what I needed. I still want to share the whole process to get the migration done is a few steps. I have a dedicated git server but you can use http.

```
git clone  git@myOldGitServer.com:myGroup/myRepo.wiki.git
git remote rename origin oldorigin
git remote add origin git@myNewGitServer.com:myGroup/myRepo.wiki.git
git fetch origin
git push --force
```

Force is necessary as there will not be common points in the imported history.

Comment: This worked for me except that I needed to cd into the cloned dir after cloning it, and I needed to do this for the push command: "git push origin master --force"

Comment: very nice! I have to add the new origin in the last step. Accidentally pushed to the old wiki - which I had deleted seconds before. "git push --set-upstream origin main"